# Telegram как получить имя telegram бота в ответе на запрос?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, npm, telegram

Telegram как получить имя telegram бота в ответе на запрос?
Какой существует для этого запрос?
Я делаю сервер на node js с модулем из npm `telebot`, если что

Существует метод 
`getMe()`
но у меня он возвращает строку 
`Promise { <pending> }`

Метод `getMe()` из офф API, который выполняется модулем из npm `telebot` 
`Telegram methods:
TeleBot use standard Telegram Bot API method names.`

> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme

```js
createBot() {
  this.bot = new Telebot({
    token: this.token,
    usePlugins: ["commandButton"]
  })

  this.setGlobalTextEvent()
  this.bot.start()
  console.log('_________')
  console.log(this.bot.getMe())
  console.log('__^^^^^__')
  return this
}
```

Comment: Что за метод getMe()? Добавьте пример кода в вопрос.

Comment: Добавила используемую функцию и немного информации

Comment: Странно, но попробуйте выполнить вместо `console.log(this.bot.getMe())` вот такое `this.bot.getMe().then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));`

Comment: сработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Используй async-await

```
async createBot() {
  this.bot = new Telebot({
    token: this.token,
    usePlugins: ["commandButton"]
  })

  this.setGlobalTextEvent()
  this.bot.start()
  console.log('_________')
  console.log(await this.bot.getMe())
  console.log('__^^^^^__')
  return this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

выполнить вместо `console.log(this.bot.getMe())` вот что 
`this.bot.getMe().then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));`